# connection to wifi

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, kernel, broadcom

I am not getting the options to connect to any WiFi networks via Ubuntu 16.04.
I think broadcom wireless driver is already installed in the laptop. But I tried installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` via terminal, here are the results.

```
jithesh@jithesh-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 327 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1 [1,544 kB]
Fetched 1,544 kB in 5s (269 kB/s)                
(Reading database ... 206249 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-62-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-62-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin for module i915_bpo
```

Could anyone please help me in solving the problem?

Comment: You have `327 not upgraded` packages! Try to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt update` first.

Comment: Broadcom drivers are for Broadcom hardware. Which one do you have? Exact model, please. Oh yes, and please fully update before anything else: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. The Broadcom driver is installed OK, but are you sure you have a Broadcom device?